# Что означает оператор "!!" в R?

Tags: r

подскажите плиз, что означает оператор `!!`

Например в этой строчке?
`filter(!is.na(!! x) & !is.na(!! y))`

Comment: https://sebastiansauer.github.io/prop_fav/   "See the !!; they mean “hey R, remember the expression I stored recently? Now take it, and ‘unquote’ it, that is, just run it!”."

Comment: вообще это два подряд идущих оператора логического отрицания. а вот в той строке, пример которой вы привели, это уже явно «unquote»-оператор, реализованный в пакете [rlang](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rlang/versions/0.1/topics/quasiquotation). см. справку `?"!!"` (если загружен пакет rlang)

Answer (score 2):

Мне самому трудно понять, что делает этот оператор, но я постараюсь объяснить.

`!!` ловит шаблоны для значений `x` и `y`. Например, рассмотрим функцию, которая будет считать среднее арифметическое по группам:

```
mean_by <- function(data, var, by) {
  data %>%
    group_by(by) %>%
    summarise(mean = mean(var, na.rm = TRUE))
}
```

Если в качестве аргументов нашей функции мы вставим названия переменных из загруженных в среду R датасетов, то наша функция выдаст ошибку:

```
starwars %>% mean_by(mass, by = gender)
> Error: Column `by` is unknown
```

Функция считала "маску", но не совсем так, как нам нужно. Для нормальной работы функции нам нужно, чтобы среда "открыла скобки" для манипуляции с входными атрибутами:

```
mean_by <- function(data, var, by) {
  data %>%
    group_by(!!enquo(by)) %>%
    summarise(mean = mean(!!enquo(var), na.rm = TRUE))
}

starwars %>% mean_by(mass, by = gender)
> # A tibble: 5 x 2...
```

Еще полезно знать про оператор curly-curly - две фигурные скобки. Оператор эксплицирует конкретно те значения, которые подходят под входные данные:

```
mean_by <- function(data, var, by) {
  data %>%
    group_by({{ by }}) %>%
    summarise(mean = mean({{ var }}, na.rm = TRUE))
}

starwars %>% mean_by(height)
```

Также есть следующая [инфа](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/nse-defuse.html) из `rlang`, которая может навести на правильную мысль:

> The main purpose of defusing evaluation of an expression is to enable
> data-masking, where an expression is evaluated in the context of a
> data frame so that you can write var instead of data$var. The
> expression is defused so it can be resumed later on, in a context
> where the data-variables have been defined.

Больше информации:

1. Пост в блоге Tidyverse: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/06/rlang-0-4-0/
2. Учебник Хэдли Викхема: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html#unquoting
3. `?dplyr_data_masking` также поможет немного разобраться

Comment: в дополнение к своему ответу делюсь ссылкой на аналогичный вопрос на англоязычном форуме: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68984415/what-does-operator-mean-in-r